# ASP.NET web forms:looks like button/link clicks do not execte the server side onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

ASP.NET 4 web forms. c#.
I had to wrap the access around LDAP(CAS). After authentication, my server side controls do not fire up on the page!. I have a grid view with "OnRowCommand" this does not fire up the server side.

```
protected void gridF_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(" row command");
            Response.End();
```

I do not see the  text.

I also have a link button outside the grid view. Clicking it also does not execute the server side.
When I take the CAS off, everything works fine.

Just to test, the client click works.This button is visible and enabled based on the user role and it is visible and enabled.

Exhausted trying to figure this one.

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="L1" runat="server" Text="Check my status." Visible="false" Enabled="false" OnClick="ChkMyStatus" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Confirm' );" />

Comment: what is your `issue` here? can you explain more clearly ?

Comment: After CAS authentication, my form stopped executing the controls. In my grid view the OnRowCommand does not get executed. My Link button does not executed the OnClick event. When I take off the CAS authentication piece everything works!

Comment: you mean to say that your `onclick` is not working? if that is the case, show us the code for that too.!

Comment: protected void gridF_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Write(" row command");
            Response.End();

                
            if (e.CommandName == "select")
            {
                string[] t = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|');
            }

        }
I do not see the above response.write and code stop.

Comment: why can't you post the `aspx` and `cs` of the gridview into the question by editing it.